# CentOS 7 Install: Error populating transaction

Tags: centos, iso, kickstart, installer-anaconda

I am having a yum issue with a CentOS 7 minimal DVD.  I've spun a custom ISO based on CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1503-01 and have only added a kickstart file that installs @core, sudo, rsyslog, and NetworkManager-tui.  **I have not added any additional packages.**  I'm only using the packages on the DVD and no mirrors.

During package installation, I get this error:

```
error populating transaction after 10 retries: failure: tar-1.26-29.el7.x86_64.rpm from anaconda: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try
```

My packaging.log indicates the installer cannot find file:///run/install/repo/tar-1.26-29.el7.x86_64.rpm **which makes sense because the rpm is in file:///run/install/repo/Packages with all the other rpms**.

Does anyone know why yum is attempting to find this one RPM from /run/install/repo/ instead of /run/install/repo/Packages?

Comment: Update: My kickstart successfully worked when I used a pristine CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1503-01 ISO and pulled the kickstart from a network share.  The issue appears to be with how I created the custom ISO.

Answer (score 1):

This specific error appears to be an artifact caused by passing the wrong arguments when generating the Custom CentOS 7 ISO. The error no longer appears when I add `-untranslated-filename` to the my `genisoimage` command.

```
sudo genisoimage -untranslated-filenames -volid 'CentOS 7 x86_64' -J -joliet-long -rational-rock -translation-table -input-charset utf-8 -x  ./lost+found -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -eltorito-alt-boot -e images/efiboot.img  -no-emul-boot -o /home/builder/custom.iso -T /home/builder/ks-iso/
```